# Does QGIS support geographical filter in WMS GetMap request?

Tags: wms, filter, qgis-server, getmap

I have a layer in QGIS SERVER which I need to filter by adding a BBOX geographical filter. I know that QGIS Server supports a kind of CQL filter, as GEOServer does, as explained here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/services.html?highlight=wms%20filter%20getmap#wms-filter

But I cannot find the right way to apply a geographical filter.

Comment: BBOX is a mandatory parameter in the WMS GetMap request. QGIS documentation is wrong in this aspect, as well as how it describes the axis order (axis are not always flipped in WMS 1.3.0, only if the CRS is officially using lat-lon or northing-easting order).

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Are you trying to limit the possible extent of the served dataset? There is an extent setting for QGIS server, although may depend on what version of QGIS server you are using.

Comment: BBOX is mandatory in a GetFeatureInfo request too, so QGIS documentation is wrong in this aspect also.  Axis order is more interesting because the WMS 1.3.0 specification tells us that `The Layer CRS has two axes, denoted x and y. The x axis is the first axis in the CRS definition, the y axis is the second axis. Depending on the particular CRS,` the axis order in WMS 1.3.0 is always minx, miny, maxx, maxy, the difference is the definition of x and y depending on the CRS.